# Approximate a function $f$ using continuous function $g$ with respect to $d(f, g) = \int_0^1 |f(x) - g(x)|dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have  the following question:

Consider the set of all Riemann integrable functions  $[0,1]$  and define the metric
$$d(f,g) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\left|f(x)-g(x)\right|dx\qquad \forall f, g \in R[0,1]$$
Also, define a function $h(x)$ as :
$$h(x) =\begin{cases} 1, & x \in [0,1/2),\\ 0, & x \in [1/2,1]\end{cases}$$
Clearly, $h \in R[0,1]$

Now I need to prove that  for every $r \gt 0$ , there exist a function $g \in C[0,1] \space$, space of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$ such that  $d(h,g) \lt r$.

I tried to solve this problem by constructing  a function such that given integral converges to some  function of type $(1/n)$ so as $n \to \infty$ ,  my functions works smoothly for all $r \gt 0$, however this strategy has failed here,

For example I considered

$$g =\begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{2}\left(1- \dfrac{1}{n}\right)(x-1/2) &   x \in [0,1/2)\\
0, & x\in [1/2,1]\end{cases}$$

then $d(g,h) = 5/16$, I have tried some  other possibilities but somehow I cannot prove this fact.

Any hints on how should I proceed ?

Comment: You should note that what you wrote is not a metric on the space of Riemann intergable functions on $[0,1]$.

Comment: $d$ is not a metric as $\int|f-g|$ does not imply $f=g.$

Comment: @zhw, Yes you are correct there seems to be a typo, unfortunately I did not see it and wasted my time on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Connect the points $$(0,1),\, (1/2-1/n,1), \,(1/2,0),\,(1,0)$$ with line segments.

Comment: I have one small doubt, even though given map is not a metric I can still  talk about $d(f,g) \lt r$ , right? because this inequality does not  uses any property of metric.

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try $g_n=1$ for $0\le x\le 1/2-1/n$ and $g_n=0$ for $1/2+1/n\le x \le 1$ and connect the points at $1/2-1/n$ and $1/2+1/n$ by a straight line.